# how do i make my turtles inherit attributes of other turtles

Tags: netlogo

i have shopper turtles and destination turtles, i want my shoppers to take the attributes of the destination turtles and set them to themselves.

```
  ask shopper [
        set destination min-one-of (turtles with [label = 789 ]  in-radius (360) )[distance myself] set attribute1 [attribute of destination] set attribute2 [attribute2 of destination] 
        set last-destination "clear" ]
```

netlogo is setting the turtle as destination, i can face it and change its color for example, but i still get "no constant".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just having a bracket problem. Use:

```
set attribute1 [ attribute1 ] of destination ; good!
```

instead of:

```
set attribute1 [attribute of destination] ; bad!
```

To put it in more "formal" NetLogo terms, `of` is a reporter that takes two arguments: a reporter block on the left (delimited by square brackets) and an agent or agentset on the right.